# Is it possible to run a Coded Ui Test in Visual Studio using Browserstack Plugin?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, browserstack

I am trying to Run Coded UI tests for Multiple Browser configurations.  Browserstack has a plug-in for Visual Studio, But Browserstack gives no information on where the plug-in plugs in.

Answer (score 0):

The BrowserStack Visual Studio plugin integrates with the 'Live' product, which is meant for manual testing. It offers a way to initiate a Live testing session from within Visual Studio.